# equivalent for CreateReply in sdk v4

Tags: botframework

I am looking for equivalent for **CreateReply** method in SDK v4
Same as explained in below article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-connector?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

How I can Send a **(non-reply)** message?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As for your question "How I can Send a (non-reply) message?":

It's there in the link you provided (section [Start a conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-connector?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#start-a-conversation)).
You can create one manually using Activity.CreateMessageActivity() for example.
You'll have to set all values manually and have an instantiated connector for it to work.

If you want to send an activity during a bot turn where you have the user's activity, you can use that activity object to populate a lot of the fields.

On the other hand, if you want to send activities to users from an outside trigger, you'll have a bit more work.

You can check this sample about proactive messages in BotBuilder-Samples: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages

Here they inject a ConcurrentDictionary as singleton to be shared by a controller and the bot.
The bot adds entries to this dictionary when users interact with it (see [AddConversationReference](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Bots/ProactiveBot.cs#L29)).
The controller iterates the entries and sends the same activity to all users who previously talked with the bot in the [BotCallback method](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs#L56).

It's not a production-ready implementation as a simple restart makes the app forget all users, but it gives you an idea of what needs to be maintained in order to send proactive messages to users.

You can read [Microsoft's article about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: So **Activity.CreateMessageActivity** exist in v4 ? Can you share examples, since link is for v3

Comment: Yes it still exists. MessageFactory.Text uses it (https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/MessageFactory.cs#L58). Although note that it wont fill many properties required to send the activity to the user, it doesn't do any magic.

Comment: So you are suggesting use same approach as proactive message example?

Comment: I don't think the CreateMessageActivity in V3 did anything different compared with the V4 one. Note how in the link you provided they fill the properties From, Recipient, Conversation, and so on. In V4 you have to do the same thing. If you can store all of that in one place to use later, you can send non reply activities to users. You weren't very specific on your question, but if you want to send proactive messages, sure, follow the article and sample project, then improve it if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry was not enough clear- I am looking for simplest way to send non-reply message to user. I would prefer to do not store input parameters and fill details by myself if possible

Comment: Non reply is very vague. What will trigger it? A timer? An external service calling an endpoint? When another user clicks in a button while talking with your bot? There are many cases. But yes the sample above is the simplest way. Check the article

Comment: André Mantas's answer is correct. Proactive messages sample is the best way to solve your situation and you will need to save the [user state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Comment: We have bot which will need human handover. So on some point it will start to forward incoming messages to external webhook application. In this application I want to be able to reply back to user connected to bot. So I want to send him messages directly from my webhook application and not from bot as reply on user message.Which article do you reference for v4?

Comment: The article is in the end of my answer. You'll want to mimic what is done there but instead of saving in a dictionary save in a shared place like database or cache so that bot writes there and your web hook reads the active conversations. I'd recommend redis. Next time give more details on your question so people can assist better

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in the Main Dialog (OnMessageActivityAsync) by doing this. See my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685181/bot-framework-4-new-activity-with-channeldata-null-reference-facebook-messenge).

```
var reply = (turnContext.Activity as Activity).CreateReply();
                                reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
                                reply.Text = "Does this work for you?
                                reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new 
                                {
                                    recipient,
                                    message
                                });

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```